# Return result from multiple activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have MainActivity along with activities:
A, B and C
The flow goes like this:

> MainActivity -> A ( gets some input ) -> B ( gets some input ) ->
>   C ( gets some input )

I want to get the input from all the activities ( A, B and C ) and save it to database.

I tried using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivityForResult(intent, id);
```

But I am only getting the result from activity C

I have a solution which is saving the data in a global object and then using it when the user is back to MainActivity, but I don't want to take that approach since I am sure this can be done with  `startActivityForResult`

What is the best way to perform this ?

Comment: What kind of data are you collecting? Simple primitives and Strings or complex Objects?

Comment: @SteveBenett Strings mainly

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get rid of your global object, you can reuse the `extras` of Intents to collect your data. This could be easier as using `startActivityForResult()` over multiply Activities. But the idea for both is the same, to reuse the `Bundle` of the Intent which called the Activity.

Have a `Bundle` as a member in your Activities and save the extras of the calling Intent to it. Something like this:

In your Activity B:

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Now put all data of B in addition to this Bundle.

```
bundle.putString(... , ...);
```

If you call f.e. C pass this Bundle to the Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

This way you can collect the data and read them out, if the user navigates back to your Activity A. If you wanna use `startActivityForResult()` just use the Intent in the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` callback.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should override the method

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ? && resultCode ==?) {
        ...
    }
}
```

in MainActivity.

and in A, B, C, you can use

```
setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)
```

to send some data.